# How can I make a field "required" only after a specific state is reached?

Tags: groovy, jira

We want to make the "Fix Version" field a required field, but only later in the workflow.
I know we can use validators to do that, but i don't want to use validators, since we have too many transitions.
Any links or pointers?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a condition on the workflow transition where you want the field to be required to be entered. This way, the user won't even see the transition until they have put a value into the field.

Alternatively, you could set a validation on the transition to ensure that the field is not empty.

Neither of these will prevent the user from putting an value for the field, transitioning to the new status and then removing the value unless you replicate the check on every subsequent transition.

Comment: Hi @ZeddZull Thanks, I'm aware of the use of validators but I want to find out if there's any other option to achieve this requirement since we have to add the validators on every tranisition.

Thanks.